# Making Comments on pull request for jupyter notebook

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter notebook's now render as html files in github, which is fantastic; however, if you want to leave a comment on a pull request I only see an option to do so on the raw notebook.  Does anyone know how you can leave comments on the html file?

If not, are people aware of other services that allow for commenting on jupyter notebooks?

Answer (score 0):

The best option is create a copy of your notebook in HTML format using nbconvert (or Download as HTML) and added this to the repo with the raw notebook, thus you add the comment in HTML version of the file.
Locally, you can see diff in HTML with [nbdime](https://nbdime.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) tool (but not comments on PR).

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how you can leave comments on the html file?

You can use [ReviewNB](https://www.reviewnb.com/) to look at visual diff for notebooks & write comments on notebook cells in a pull request.

Disclaimer: I built ReviewNB.